# Styling the WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to make a style for WPF treeview with the following rules:

- The look of the tree has to be defined in the style;
- The look of tree's items has to be defined in the style;
- The look of tree item's contents (header) has to be defined in the style with option to be customized outside the style.

I've extracted `TreeView`'s and `TreeItem`'s default style and made some modifications. Currently, skeleton of my code looks like the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            ...
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
            <TreeViewItem header="Inner" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I've customized look of the expand button, to check, if everything's OK. The code presented above works as planned.

[image: Correct styling]

But then I want to customize the look of the `TreeViewItem`s outside the style. I write:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    ...
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>

    <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Sub" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The items are styled as I want, but the expander button returns to its default look.

[image: Incorrect styling]

How can I achieve a styling mechanism I want?

You can download the [whole sample source](http://pastebin.com/ZVrcLQ9f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a `Style` that is *based on* your default `Style`. If that is correct, then you can use the `Style.BasedOn` property if you provide your default `Style` with an `x:Key` value:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DefaultTreeViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            ...
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you can base your *overriding* `Style` on the default one like this:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTreeViewStyle}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                ...
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

The new `Style` will have all of the settings from the default `Style` plus any additional settings that you provide here.

Actually, thinking about it a bit more, I think that you can base your *overriding* `Style` on the default one without setting the `x:Key` value on the default one like this:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                ...
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: It seem to work. But is there a way to achieve the same result without using BasedOn? I may modify the styles for the `TreeView` as well if needed. I may also create custom control based on `TreeView`, but I'm unsure, if that helps.

Comment: What I want to say is, that if you use default style for `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem`, you don't have to use BasedOn to custom style items. I would like to apply style to `TreeView` in such way, that it would also be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, `BasedOn` is as good as it gets with *customising* existing `Style`s.